# How do I compute $-6(-4)^{n-1} + 8(-4)^{n-2}$?

Tags: arithmetic

How do I compute $-6(-4)^{n-1}$ + $8(-4)^{n-2}$ ?

I recall that as long as the number from both operands (in this case: -4) are the same, I can actually "add" them together. But the problem is the -6 from the first operand and the +8 from the second operand makes the math difficult right?

So should I just factor it by $(-4)^{n-2}$?

What are my options?

Comment: -6a^(n-1) + 8a^(n-2) = a^(n-2)[-6a + 8] =a^(n-2)*32 you can finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(-4)^{n-1}(-6+8(-4)^{-1})$$
$$(-4)^{n-1}(-6-2)$$
$$(-4)^{n}\frac{-8}{-4}=2(-4)^n$$

Comment: How come you factor by (-4)^(n-1) instead of (-4)^(n-2)? Just a preference?

Comment: @Nicholas Is there a problem in my answer?

Comment: Oh ok, now I see why you divided by -4. You broke (-4)^(n-1) into two pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $-6(-4)^{n-1}=-6\times (-4)\times (-4)^{n-2}=24(-4)^{n-2}$

Comment: Does your technique have a name? Is the answer: 30*(-4)^$(n-2)$?

Comment: Hahahahahaaa, No.

Comment: That's a pretty cool technique. I never knew you could do that

Answer (score 0):

This problem is looking to assess your comfort with the properties of exponents. Recall these general properties...

- $x^a x^b = x^{a+b}$
- $\dfrac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$
- $(x^a)^b = (x^b)^a = x^{ab}$
- $x^{-a} = \dfrac{1}{x^a}$ for $x \ne 0$

So, solving the problem using a slightly alternative method than the others (for the sake of variety):

$$-6(-4)^{n-1} + 8(-4)^{n-2}$$
$$ = -6(-4)^{-1}(-4)^n + 8(-4)^{-2}(-4)^n$$
$$ = \dfrac{-6}{-4}(-4)^n + \dfrac{8}{4^2}(-4)^n$$
$$ = (-4)^n\left(\dfrac{3}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$ = 2(-4)^n$$